# (Windows 7) Is it possible to reserve one monitor for a single application?

Tags: windows-7, vmware, desktop, user-interface

I'm looking for a means of 'Locking' an application to one monitor on my multi monitor display, so that only this single specific application is permanently docked there, and has exclusive use of that monitor.

**Use Case:**

I want a VMWare virtual machine instance, running a Linux OS to have exclusive use of one monitor, and for the host OS to behave as though only the two remaining monitors are available to it (IE windows on the host OS cannot be moved to the monitor assigned to the VMWare instance). The goal is to be able to use two operating systems at once, but use the same mouse, keyboard and have shared disk locations between each OS. While I could design a hardware based solution, using a VM is more efficient and the UI feels easier to manage, so I would like to see if this is possible. Is it?

[image]

Is there a method I can use to achieve this, or a type of software that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows as a host OS, then I think it's impossible to forbid Windows to use one of his monitors.
This is because Windows must, in fact, be able to see and use this monitor, so that VMWare (that run on Windows) can use the monitor to show you the guest OS.

But you can still use some tools to ease your life: [**DualMonitorTool**](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/)
http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/
This is a set of free tools to manage multi monitor setup.

You can use them to have an application always start on a specific monitor, or to move window between monitors with a hotkey, or to minimize windows only on a specific monitor... and many other useful things.

Comment: That looks like a useful tool, but it's not going to help me to do what I want here according to the tools listed.